# Can't delete post fastapi

Tags: python, api, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm working on some simple blog, and now if I try to delete post, I get an error.
Switching from 'get' to 'delete' method didnt help me.
So I think problem in sqlalchemy
Here's the router:

```
@router.get('/delete/{id}')
def delete(id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db), current_user: UserAuth = Depends(get_current_user)):
    return db_post.delete_post(id, db, current_user.id)
```

DbPost model:

```
class DbPost(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'post'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    image_url = Column(String)
    image_url_type = Column(String)
    caption = Column(String)
    timestamp = Column(DateTime)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = relationship('DbUser', back_populates='items')
```

And function:

```
def delete_post(id: int, db: Session, user_id: int):
    current_post = db.query(DbPost).filter(DbPost.id == id).first()
    if not current_post:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
                detail=f'Post with id {id} not found.')
    if current_post.user_id != user_id:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN,
                detail='Only post creator can delete post')
        
    db.delete(current_post)
    db.commit()
    return 'Post was succesfully deleted'
```

Authentication and other routers work fine.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aleksandr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Instagram-clone-MvbemEoR/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 407, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "/home/aleksandr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Instagram-clone-MvbemEoR/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/aleksandr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Instagram-clone-MvbemEoR/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 270, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/aleksandr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Instagram-clone-MvbemEoR/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 124, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/aleksandr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Instagram-clone-MvbemEoR/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/home/aleksandr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Instagram-clone-MvbemEoR/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/home/aleksandr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Instagram-clone-MvbemEoR/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 75, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/home/aleksandr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Instagram-clone-MvbemEoR/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 64, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/home/aleksandr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Instagram-clone-MvbemEoR/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/home/aleksandr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Instagram-clone-MvbemEoR/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/aleksandr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Instagram-clone-MvbemEoR/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 680, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/aleksandr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Instagram-clone-MvbemEoR/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 275, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/aleksandr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Instagram-clone-MvbemEoR/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 65, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/home/aleksandr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Instagram-clone-MvbemEoR/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 235, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/home/aleksandr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Instagram-clone-MvbemEoR/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 163, in run_endpoint_function
    return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
  File "/home/aleksandr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Instagram-clone-MvbemEoR/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/concurrency.py", line 41, in run_in_threadpool
    return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args)
  File "/home/aleksandr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Instagram-clone-MvbemEoR/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/to_thread.py", line 31, in run_sync
    return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
  File "/home/aleksandr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Instagram-clone-MvbemEoR/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 937, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
  File "/home/aleksandr/.local/share/virtualenvs/Instagram-clone-MvbemEoR/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 867, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
  File "/home/aleksandr/Programming/Sites/Instagram-clone/routers/post.py", line 48, in delete
    return db_post.delete_post(id, db, current_user.id)
AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Comment: My guess is that `id` is messing with the builtin function name `id`. Can you try this again with a less ambiguous name, something like `my_id`?

Comment: It seems like `current_user` is a `Query` object. What does `get_current_user` look loke?